# How can i configure Hazelcast distributed maps using Wildfly with hazelcast-jca

Tags: wildfly, hazelcast

I'm trying to use Hazelcast with Wildfly.

Following the instructions provided in the Hazelcast website I could start a cluster using the hazelcast-jca and hazelcast-jca-rar.

What I don't know, is where do I configure the distributed maps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to configure the maps in hazelcast.xml and put the configuration into your classpath.
http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest/manual/html-single/index.html#map

Here you can find some code samples for Hazelcast Resource Adapter:
https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-code-samples/tree/master/hazelcast-integration/jca-ra

Documentation for Hazelcast Resource Adapter as you already know:
http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest/manual/html-single/index.html#integrating-into-j2ee